# Don't understand why output is incorrect

Tags: c++, output

I'm currently doing a Zybooks lesson for my C++ class and we're going over while loops. In this question, it wants me to calculate how many years it takes for a bank account to double it's initial balance. There is also an annual contribution added. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
   const double RATE = 5;
   const double INITIAL_BALANCE = 10000;
   const double TARGET = 2 * INITIAL_BALANCE;

   cout << "Annual contribution: " << endl;
   double contribution; 
   cin >> contribution;

   double balance = INITIAL_BALANCE;
   int year = 0;

   while (balance < TARGET)
   {
      year++;
      double interest = balance * RATE / 100;
      balance = balance + interest + contribution;
   }

   cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
   cout << "Balance: " << balance << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I used this as an answer but was met with this unexpected result:

```
Output differs. See highlights below.

Input
100

Your output

Annual contribution: 
Year: 13
Balance: 20627.8

Expected output

Annual contribution: 
Year: 13
Balance: 20527.8
```

Comment: It seems the bank is considering you withdraw the money when it  becomes double the initial amount. So it is not adding contribution point.

Comment: You should print out what the values of `balance` is in the loop to see what the issue is.  Second, `while (balance < TARGET)` -- Floating point (`double`) is not exact.  This may end up with the loop not executing the number of times you expected, all due to `balance` being computed within the `while` loop using `interest` as part of the calculation.

Comment: What is expected result? For me it seems to be ok: https://godbolt.org/z/5h3185jj8

Answer (score 0):

I see the expected output and your output differs by a 100, i.e. your  `contribution`. Maybe the evaluation system doesn't add annual contribution once your target is reached. The below code gets your required output, but I think your code should have been the correct answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
   const double RATE = 5;
   const double INITIAL_BALANCE = 10000;
   const double TARGET = 2 * INITIAL_BALANCE;

   cout << "Annual contribution: " << endl;
   double contribution; 
   cin >> contribution;

   double balance = INITIAL_BALANCE;
   int year = 0;

   while (balance < TARGET)
   {
      year++;
      double interest = balance * RATE / 100;
      balance = balance + interest;
      if (balance < TARGET) {
        balance += contribution;
      }
   }

   cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
   cout << "Balance: " << balance << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you can simply subtract the contribution out side while loop.

Comment: If doing outside the loop, you can't "simply subtract". After subtracting, `balance` could be less than the `TARGET`. @ManojBhat

Comment: Let me rephrase it. Only subtract if 'balance-contribution>TARGET' that way you don't have to check each time in the loop.

Comment: Yeah, that would work and is probably more "efficient".

Answer (score 0):

This is because the last time the loop is being executed (at year=13), `balance` is less than `TARGET` but, after adding a `contribution` and `interest` into it, it jumps out of the loop with `contribution` and `interest` added to it.

So, the solution can be to use an `if` statement within the `while` loop to check if it exceeds the `TARGET`; if it does, then don't add contribution into it.

Replace your `while` loop with the following:

```
while (balance < TARGET)
   {
      year++;
      double interest = balance * RATE / 100;
      balance = balance + interest;
      if (balance < TARGET) {
        balance += contribution;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're making a contribution after the 13th year even though the target has been reached.

I would restructure to something like this, in order to only check the condition once:

```
while (true)
{
    year++;
    double interest = balance * RATE / 100;
    balance += interest;
    if (balance >= TARGET)
    {
        break;
    }
    balance += contribution;
}
```